# Svelte watch an object property

Tags: svelte

I have a list of events

```
let searchedEvents=[] // events array which will be filled with search results later
```

When this array is populated(with say `n` results), the ui will show `n` forms which user will be able to edit. The first form (`searchedEvents[0]`) edited is supposed to update all other forms(e.g. say there is a field `num` in form 1. If first form's `num` field is updated, all other forms should show same value for this field).

To achieve this, I am having an `eventZero = searchedEvents[0]`(and this statement is run whenever `searchedEvents` array is updated.

Then I am watching this `eventZero.num` like this:

`$: myWatch(eventZero.num)`

But whenever user edits the num field in the form, this does not fire `myWatch`.

Even watching directly like `$: myWatch(eventZero)` does not work.
So how do I achieve this in svelte?

Comment: Could you maybe make a small [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1) of the logic?

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to watch the whole array but set up the watcher so it only reacts if a value is changed that satisfies the conditions (being the first value, in this case). So, here's my approach:

```
// App.svelte
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import InputField from './InputField.svelte';

    let searchedEvents = [];

    // setting up the initial array
    let n = 10;
    onMount(() => {
        searchedEvents = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => ({ num: i, idx: i }));
    });

    // function to set array values programatically
    const setToFirst = (arr) => arr.map(({ num, ...rest }, i, d) => ({ num: d[0].num, ...rest }))
    
    // setting up watcher with "oldValue"
    let watchedNum = 0 ?? searchedEvents[0].num
    $: if (searchedEvents.length && searchedEvents[0].num !== watchedNum) {
        searchedEvents = setToFirst(searchedEvents)
        watchedNum = searchedEvents[0].num
    }
    
</script>

{#each searchedEvents as event}
    {event.idx}: <InputField bind:val={event.num} /><br />
{/each}
```

```
// InputField.svelte
<script>
    export let val;
</script>

<input bind:value={val} />
```

You can find the working snippet [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/12e31bfe73a74d898acd881fb99b42aa?version=3.44.1).

Answer (score 0):

at the location where you update the array `searchedEvents.push(...)` make an `searchedEvents = searchedEvents` to tell svelte you update a deep object or array because svelte is only watching the first level of variables,
if you are using a form you can make a form change function that is called every time the user updates the form `<input on:change={() => searchedEvents = searchedEvents}>`

[REPL1](https://svelte.dev/repl/dfde6baffda64b9a94e3da27c037b820?version=3.55.1) - [REPL2-Input-Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/a65088e110dc45f79f43633acbc761c3?version=3.56.0)